# Varnish acts differently on different browser, why?

Tags: caching, browser, varnish

On Firefox, Varnish is in play, but not on Google Chrome. Possible? Why?

Comment: Eh, please tell us why you would think that. What did you observe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One other possible reason could be that you have a session cookie in Chrome that causes Varnish to pass the request to the backend.

Comment: YES. I check the cookie in the request. They are different. It caused by the first visit. The response set a new cookie to Chrome client.

Comment: Cookies usually break caching unless you add the cookie to the hash.
[https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleCacheCookies](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleCacheCookies)

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is normalization of the Accept-Encoding header, both Firefox and Chrome send a different one. Add this to your sub vcl_recv():

```
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
    if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg)$") {
        # No point in compressing these
        remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
    } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
    } else {
        # unkown algorithm
        remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    }
}
```

This is also documented in the [Varnish manual on the "Vary" header](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/vary.html).

Comment: I have that but still Chrome is not caching

Comment: How does your vcl_hash look like? Are you seeing headers like 'Vary: User-Agent' in varnishlog? If so, that instructs varnish to keep a different cache per User-Agent (and that's pretty much unique since it also covers OS-strings etc)

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
       if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
           set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
       } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
           set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
       } else {
           # unknown language. Remove the accept-language header and
           # use the backend default.
           unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
       }
    }
   //add below condition along with above code in vcl_recv subroutine.
   if(req.http.User-Agent) {
       unset req.http.User-Agent;
   }
```

Comment: Other wise you can write below code in vcl_deliver sub routine to unset Vary in response header.                                                                         
    unset resp.http.Vary;